# Array counting Error

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I am trying to count from the following associative array in two's key->value filter, by Key-gender and Key-rname, Please see below ...

```
<pre>
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [fname] => jone
            [lname] => jani
            [gender] => m
            [rname] => N
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [fname] => jani
            [lname] => jone
            [gender] => m
            [rname] => N
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [fname] => sara
            [lname] => bulbula
            [gender] => w
            [rname] => D
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [fname] => hani
            [lname] => hanu
            [gender] => w
            [rname] => P
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [fname] => ttttttt
            [lname] => sssssss
            [gender] => m
            [rname] => C
        )

)
</pre>
```

What i want the result is as follows..

```
rname   gender
        m  w 
N       2  0
D       0  1
P       0  1
C       1  0
total   3  2
```

Some help please?

Comment: so where's your code that has an error?

Comment: I can count only in one key-value...but i coudn't in two .i use this small function, but counts only in one Key..public function array_column($array, $key) {
            $field = array();
            foreach($array as $realKey => $value) {
                if (isset($value[$key])) {
                    $field[$realKey] = $value[$key];
                }            
            }
            return $field;
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see your code so I am trying to make own code.

```
$arr = array(
    array(
        'fname' => 'jone',
        'lname' => 'jani',
        'gender' => 'm',
        'rname' => 'N'
    ),
    array(
        'fname' => 'jani',
        'lname' => 'jone',
        'gender' => 'm',
        'rname' => 'N'
    ),
    array(
        'fname' => 'sara',
        'lname' => 'bulbula',
        'gender' => 'w',
        'rname' => 'D'
    ),
    array(
        'fname' => 'hani',
        'lname' => 'hanu',
        'gender' => 'w',
        'rname' => 'P'
    ),
    array(
        'fname' => 'ttttttt',
        'lname' => 'sssssss',
        'gender' => 'm',
        'rname' => 'C'
    ),
);

$matrix = array();
foreach (array('N', 'D', 'P', 'C', 'total') as $name) {
    foreach (array('m', 'w') as $gender) {
        $matrix[$name][$gender] = 0;
    }
}

foreach ($arr as $el) {
    $matrix[$el['rname']][$el['gender']] += 1;
    $matrix['total'][$el['gender']] += 1;
}


echo '<pre>';
print_r($matrix);
echo '</pre>';

// OR dynamicaly keys

$matrix = array();
foreach ($arr as $el) {
    if (!isset($matrix[$el['rname']][$el['gender']])) 
        $matrix[$el['rname']][$el['gender']] = 0;

    if (!isset($matrix['total'][$el['gender']])) 
        $matrix['total'][$el['gender']] = 0;

    $matrix[$el['rname']][$el['gender']] += 1;
    $matrix['total'][$el['gender']] += 1;
}


echo '<pre>';
print_r($matrix);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Your first foreach does not dynamically create a count based on rnames, what happens if there is an rname introduced as `x` for example? You will need to modify the first foreach to accept this argument

Comment: That is really nice solution Men, Thanks. Mr.Slawomir.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar function which I have used to do something similar to your request.. So this is just a copy and paste, because you have shown a lack of code.. This returns an array as your expecting.. Just iterating over this returned array, is something you will need to research into yourself

```
function Array_Counter($Array){
        $Return_Arr = array(
            "M" => array(),
            "F" => array()
        );
    foreach ($Array AS $Arr){
        if ($Arr['gender'] === "m"){
            //Is Male
            @$Return_Arr['M'][$Arr['rname']] ++; // Message supressed due to returning undefined index warnings... Which because of not using isset().. Will still work
        }elseif ($Arr['gender'] === "f"){
            // Is Female
            @$Return_Arr['F'][$Arr['rname']] ++; // Message supressed due to returning undefined index warnings... Which because of not using isset().. Will still work
        }

    }
    return $Return_Arr;

}

 $Array = array (
    array(
        "gender" => "m",
        "rname" => "c"
    ),
    array(
        "gender"=> "f",
        "rname" => "d"
    ),
    array (
        "gender" => "f",
        "rname" => "a"
    ),
        array (
        "gender" => "f",
        "rname" => "x"
    ),
        /* Array shortened for exampling purposes */

);


$Array_Count = Array_Counter($Array);
```

Using the function as followed

```
echo "<pre>";
    print_r($Array_Count);
echo "</pre>";
```

Returns:

```
Array
(
    [M] => Array
        (
            [c] => 1
            [j] => 1
            [g] => 1
            [d] => 1
        )

    [F] => Array
        (
            [d] => 3
            [a] => 1
            [x] => 1
        )

)
```